# Managing SSH Host Keys in 20.04 Autoinstall/Cloud Init

Tags: system-installation

I want to manage the generation of SSH host keys during a build of a 20.04 VM. The default is that on first boot cloud-init deletes any host keys and creates fresh ones.

The autoinstall docs don't talk about this. The cloud init docs talk about being able to use the "ssh_deletekeys: false" parameter to control this.

I've tried putting this at the top of my user-data file. i.e.

```
#cloud-config
ssh_deletekeys: false
autoinstall:
...
```

That didn't work. I also tried manually adding it to the `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data` prior to first reboot, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put `ssh_deletekeys: false` in the configuration file at `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`. At least it worked for me under Debian 10.

Example:

```
# The top level settings are used as module
# and system configuration.

ssh_deletekeys: false

# A set of users[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with cloud-init and ubuntu 20.04, my fix was the following:

1. I provisioned the image using the autoinstall file
2. I after the provision I run this command `sudo cloud-init clean` to remove the cloud-init cache to make able cloud-init to run like a first boot (it will create the new host keys)
3. After that I sysprep the image and builds a new vm